# Letter logo similitude controversy

Tags: logo, design-principles, stock-images, abstract

Since I was unable to find good enough imo C-logo, I created one myself.
[image]

As you can see it is highly abstractive and full of nostalgic elements from my past. However, due to the regal middle node it is rather unclear whether it resembles "e" or "c". Evident in everything, this is primary opinion-based, although I need a professional styler advice.

Should I rename it to "e" or the similarity with "e" isn't as much greatly noticeable or should I spend some time, eventually in ruining this image in order to remove the middle node despite it being far from inferior ?

Comment: If it is a **logo** you don't rename ANYTHING to match random artwork... you create artwork to **identify a company, service, or product**.  This question makes little sense to me.

Comment: The use of the word "logo" may be a language barrier/poor choice. The person may be doing an assignment related to the alphabet.

Comment: Whatever it is, whether it is a logo or not.. it doesn't change the thing and is of no importance to YOU. Still wondering why people prefer to discuss this, other than the actual problem. Just like go-me did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no rules about renaming or not **your** company; it's your logo and your company, you do what you want. After all, a lot of people name their businesses based on symbols they like.

If this graphic has a special meaning to you, it's alright to use it. Especially in design, there's no limits to express your own style and since it's for yourself, you truly have no limits in what you want to do with that design either. Dali loved rhinoceros horns and ants... it didn't make sense to 99.999% of the planet and it didn't matter; he wasn't selling cars or shoes, he was selling his art. Go for what you like if you do something for yourself. E or C, it doesn't matter.

Lot of designers create logos with initials or letters only. Your graphic is just another way of showing a letter. The only problem I can see you may have with it is the RGB colors that will look a bit less bright when you'll convert it to a CMYK version for printing (if you ever need printed material.)

Just a side note, I think the colored part looks a bit like a bird.

---

**Just throwing suggestions... if it can help**

If you want to slightly modify your logo to a C, and don't mind losing that bit in the middle, there isn't so much work to do to modify it.

I don't know if this is what you think would look more like a C but here's a sample of your image modified. I only filled that area with the same black as your background, and used the brush tool at 105pt with no hardness for the part closer to the colored area.

[image: Modified C logo]

**Here's another variation if you want to accentuate the C (all RGB color):**

[image: C logo with thick font in turquoise]

I can see how this graphic could make a nice logo if you keep it in a black square box and write your company name below or on the right with a thick sans-serif in black. Maybe that's not a style you like, maybe it is.

[image: Logo Suggestion1]

[image: Logo suggestion 2]

Comment: The majority of people don't get that it is created for multiple purposes. It could be the well-known "C" as for "Copyright", Initials, "The C Programming Language", "See". If it is a an "e" just that it has less meaning.

Comment: No one really asked you, besides doing it in a condescending way. You forgot one extra meaning; there's also C for communication skills!

Comment: (Wouldn't that be CS)

Answer (score 2):

There is no point in renaming, redesigning or ruining something when the end goal is unclear. Did you set out to make a "C"? Then re-do it. Did you set out to make an alphabet? Then maybe re-name, but first compare to the other letters. It is always the **purpose** and not the tweak you should focus on.

> As you can see it is [...] full of nostalgic elements from my past.

No one can see that. Just like no one can see the original purpose. Design is communication. That's whats currently lacking in your design.

Comment: "... That's whats currently lacking in your design." pity.